# Sql search that allows for unselected options

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form with three search options.

```
SELECT users.* FROM users WHERE users.genre = ? AND users.country = ? AND users.city = ?
```

This query only returns a result if all three criteria are met

```
SELECT users.* FROM users WHERE users.genre = ? OR users.country = ? OR users.city = ?
```

this query only returns a result if only one criteria is correctly met

What I need to happen is:

If someone submits "Australia" for country and leaves genre and city blank they get all results for Australia.

```
(city=Australia&genre=&country=)
```

If someone submits "Australia" for country and "rock" for genre and leaves blank they get all results for Australia and "rock".

```
(city=Australia&genre=&rockcountry=)
```

at the moment if I leave a value blank on the form it gives me no results as I think it's searching MySQL for empty cells?

thanx

```
 <php
$Recordset1 = new WA_MySQLi_RS("Recordset1",$alpha,1);
$Recordset1->setQuery("SELECT users.* FROM users WHERE users.genre = ? AND users.country = ? AND users.city = ?");
$Recordset1->bindParam("s", "".((isset($_POST["genre"]))?$_POST["genre"]:"")  ."", "-1"); //WAQB_Param1
$Recordset1->bindParam("s", "".((isset($_POST["country"]))?$_POST["country"]:"")  ."", "-1"); //WAQB_Param2
$Recordset1->bindParam("s", "".((isset($_POST["city"]))?$_POST["city"]:"")  ."", "-1"); //WAQB_Param3
$Recordset1->execute();
?>
```

thought this may work

```
<?php
if ((isset($_POST["country"]) && $_POST["country"] != '')) 
{?>
<?php
$Recordset1 = new WA_MySQLi_RS("Recordset1",$alpha,1);
$Recordset1->setQuery("SELECT users.* FROM users WHERE users.country = ?");
$Recordset1->bindParam("s", "".((isset($_POST["country"]))?$_POST["country"]:"")  ."", "-1"); //WAQB_Param2
$Recordset1->execute();
?>
<?php } ?>

<?php
if ((isset($_POST["country"]) && $_POST["country"] != '') && (isset($_POST["city"]) && $_POST["city"] != '')) 
{?>
<?php
$Recordset1 = new WA_MySQLi_RS("Recordset1",$alpha,1);
$Recordset1->setQuery("SELECT users.* FROM users WHERE users.genre = ? AND users.country = ? AND users.city = ?");
$Recordset1->bindParam("s", "".((isset($_POST["country"]))?$_POST["country"]:"")  ."", "-1"); //WAQB_Param2
$Recordset1->bindParam("s", "".((isset($_POST["city"]))?$_POST["city"]:"")  ."", "-1"); //WAQB_Param3
$Recordset1->execute();
?>
<?php } ?>


<?php
if ((isset($_POST["country"]) && $_POST["country"] != '') && (isset($_POST["city"]) && $_POST["city"] != '') && (isset($_POST["genre"]) && $_POST["genre"] != '')) 
{?>
<?php
$Recordset1 = new WA_MySQLi_RS("Recordset1",$alpha,1);
$Recordset1->setQuery("SELECT users.* FROM users WHERE users.genre = ? AND users.country = ? AND users.city = ?");
$Recordset1->bindParam("s", "".((isset($_POST["genre"]))?$_POST["genre"]:"")  ."", "-1"); //WAQB_Param1
$Recordset1->bindParam("s", "".((isset($_POST["country"]))?$_POST["country"]:"")  ."", "-1"); //WAQB_Param2
$Recordset1->bindParam("s", "".((isset($_POST["city"]))?$_POST["city"]:"")  ."", "-1"); //WAQB_Param3
$Recordset1->execute();
?>
<?php } ?>
```

but its very verbose and does not cover all the search options, e.g. if a user chooses country and genre, it's not covered above unless i write code for every specific search.

Comment: Can you try to set NULL value if not found in queryString. And also use TRIM function in search for better result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider building your WHERE clause dynamically:

```
$sql = "SELECT * WHERE ";
if (isset($_POST["genre"]) {
    $sql .= 'users.genre = :genre OR ';
}
... same for other criteria

// chop off the extra ' OR ' on the end (simpler than tracking when to add one above)
$sql = substr($sql, -4);

$Recordset1->setQuery($sql);
if (isset($_POST["genre"])) {
    $Recordset1->bindParam(':genre', $_POST["genre"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
}
... same for other criteria
```

Side note, I'm not sure why you have all those `?> </php` pairs scattered through your code. They can do nothing but harm.